# Keyboard fails after upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, keyboard, touchpad

I upgraded my [laptop](https://support.toshiba.com/support/staticContentDetail?contentId=4013838&isFromTOCLink=false) (Toshiba [Satellite C40-B](https://support.toshiba.com/support/modelHome?freeText=1200012134)) from 16.04 to 18.04. 
My laptop keypad and touchpad worked AOK in version 16.04, but with 18.04, they don't work, which leaves me stuck in the login page. The same keypad works fine in the BIOS/Setup page and with Microsoft Windows.

Comment: For troubleshooting purposes only, what happens when you plug in an external USB keyboard?. Please click on `edit` above at left to add your response to the original post.